# How do I place an SPA in a S3 state website subdirectory using rewrite rules?

Tags: rewrite, amazon-s3

I have successfully deployed AngularJS apps to S3 in the past with `html5mode` enabled in order to allow for hash-less URLs.

For my current project, however, I need to place the Angular portion of the site into a subdirectory (`/app`) and am having significant trouble.

I have tried a few things, most notably the following, but it results in a redirect loop, and I don't believe there is anyway to employ negative rule matching to avoid such an issue:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>app/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>app/#</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

I have also tried handling 404's by directing them to app/ (also `/app/#`, `/app/index.html`, `/app/index.html#`) but nothing has worked to the effect which makes my app work in the way I desire. An example which causes unexpected errors in my angular app:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <HostName>mytest.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyWith>app/index.html</ReplaceKeyWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

What rule(s) can I use to have all requests beginning with `/app` directed to `/app/#`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were really close, but there are a couple of subtleties with S3 Routing Rules that you need to take into account:

The `HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals` element is one form of negative matching, but while an object that isn't present may cause a 404, it also may cause a 403.  This depends on the bucket policy.  You'll need to determine which is the case for you, or, just handle both conditions in the routing rules.

Also, the routing rules are not processed by best match -- they appear to be processed by first match... so you actually want to build your routing rules with the longest prefixes first.

The following is tested and works for me.  If it doesn't work for you, be sure your browser cache is clear (since S3 routing rule redirects are 301s, and browsers love to cache them) and verify that you have no other redirects with shorter prefixes that incorrectly capture the requests.

I assume that you already have a document at /app/index.html, and that "Index Document" in the console lists "index.html" as the index document.  This makes it so that requests for /app/ will return /app/index.html *but* the browser's address bar will still read "/app/".

Generating the redirect we need for the SPA... if we see a request with a prefix of /app/ and the object doesn't exist, we want to redirect the request by replacing /app/ with /app/#/, but *only if* there's no such file.  The "no such file" test is crucial because otherwise this rule would result in requests for "/app/" being redirected, in an infinite loop, and the 404 test may not be the correct test, as mentioned above.  My buckets return 403 on missing objects, since the requester does not have permission to know whether the object exists, or not.  You'll need to find the right value for your configuration.

With the following rule in place, /app/anyfoo gets redirected to /app/#/anyfoo but /app/ doesn't, because /app/ actually matches the index document.

```
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>app/</KeyPrefixEquals>
        <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>app/#/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

Finally, we need requests for "app" be redirected to "app/" so that S3 will understand that the index document is needed.

Your bucket may already be doing this part, and if it is, then the above should not break it, since the redirection only occurs when the key doesn't match an object, and /app/ will not trigger that rule, since it implicitly returns the index document.

However... in the bucket where I tested this, there's a final rule that redirects *all* requests, where the object doesn't exist, to the same path at an entirely different hostname.

This caused /app, without the trailing slash, for me, to follow that wildcard redirecgt to a different site, which was wrong.  If you have such a rule and you need to get /app to correctly return the /app/index.html page, then the following rule, *placed after the above rule*, accomplishes that purpose in much the same way S3 would have handled it, had I not had the catchall rule in place.

This final rule is supposed to match only "/app" ... it would also match requests for "/app/" itself, but since "/app/" doesn't generate a 403, it doesn't match, so there's no issue there.  It would also match "/app/anyfoo" but those requests will never arrive here, because they've already been captured and redirected by the prior rule.

```
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals>app</KeyPrefixEquals>
        <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>403</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>app/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
</RoutingRule>
```

Of course, the comical side-effect of this last rule is that a nonsense request, e.g. for "/applesauce" redirects to "/app/lesauce" and then to "/app/#/lesauce" but this is rather harmless, since the redirections depend on the referenced objects not actually existing.  If /applesauce is a legitimate path, the redirect won't fire.  You can work around this by redirecting "app" at the key level in object metadata instead of a routing rule, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader, since this final step may not be necessary, depending on bucket configuration.

Comment: With a direct copy-paste, I still got an infinite redirect when reloading any page/view. I added a trailing slash to `KeyPrefixEquals` and `/#` to `ReplaceKeyPrefixWith`, and now it works really well. Possibly an Angular idiosyncrasy. I really appreciate your answer for the fact that it worked and also gave me a better understanding of the S3 rules. Thanks!